# Gradient Boosted Decision Trees How to Find Prediction of Each Tree?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, boosting

I'm doing a project. I have a classification problem that I should solve using gradient boosted decision trees. What I want to do is create a matrix that gives prediction of each decision tree for each sample. For example if I have 100 samples and 100 trees, I should have 100x100 matrix. i, j th entry gives the prediction of jth tree for ith sample.

I'm using sklearn and problem is I can't get prediction by each tree.

So far I tried:

```
newgb=gb.estimators_[0][0].fit(X_train, y_train)
print(newgb.score(X_train, y_train))
```

where gb is already a fitted model. What I understood from documentation of sklearn

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor.staged_predict

> .estimators_

should return (number-of-trees x 1) matrix, each entry contains a tree that used by our model. By gb.estimators_[0][0] I tried to access to the first tree, and predict it with score. What I get as output is:

```
[0.12048193 0.95       0.95       0.95       0.95       0.95
 0.95       0.95       0.95       0.95       0.12048193 0.95
 0.95       0.95       0.12048193 0.12048193 0.12048193 0.12048193
...]
```

None of them are 1 or 0, like it should be(it is binary classification) and values repeat themselves like 0.95 and 0.12. I didn't use any likelihood function either so

> .score()

supposed to give me only 1's and 0's.

I don't know how to get predictions for each individual tree. I don't know what I do wrong either.

Comment: Regressor or classifier?  - the link in your question is to  GBregressor..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sklearn's GradientBoostingClassifier is not implemented using trees of DecisionTreeClassifiers. It uses regressors for both classification and regression. You can read it [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html):

> GB builds an additive model in a forward stage-wise fashion; it allows
>   for the optimization of arbitrary differentiable loss functions. In
>   each stage n_classes_ regression trees are fit on the negative
>   gradient of the binomial or multinomial deviance loss function. Binary
>   classification is a special case where only a single regression tree
>   is induced.

This means it will not be as simple as calling predict on the tree estimators. I previously suggested it could be implemented using sklearn's private methods, but as [BenReiniger](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/55122/ben-reiniger) pointed out sklearn has already implemented this for us in the method `staged_predict`.

Comment: I started with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20615750/how-do-i-output-the-regression-prediction-from-each-tree-in-a-random-forest-in-p At that link they claim it is doable. I'm a little confused. If sklearn not implemented using trees why should I look its implementation also?

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear. It does use trees, but it uses DecisionTreeRegressors (predicts loss) and not DecisionTreeClassifiers (that predicts a class). The sections of code I pointed to is how sklearn goes from loss to a class.

Comment: The ticket you linked uses random forest, which works like you have tried to do it. Boosting is fundamentally different where each tree is dependent on the tree that came before it. Maybe this can help: http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/01/23/a-kaggle-master-explains-gradient-boosting/

Comment: sorry for confusion, I'm just tired couldn't realize

Comment: @J.Smith The `predict_stages` appears to be a more private method; the public `staged_predict` and `staged_predict_proba` call it:  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.staged_predict

Comment: @BenReiniger nice! I just figured it should be reverse-engineerable by backtracking the predict method, so I totally missed that it is right there. :)